# Adding ImageViews dynamically in a Layout Android

Tags: android, animation, android-imageview

I'm trying to add dynamically some image views on a layout, because I have to move them in the same time, one after another, along a path.

This is a part of my code, but I get this error: the specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

I don't know how to solve this.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        int random1=random(5);
        int random2=random(9);


        for(int i=1;i<=random2;i++) {

            RelativeLayout layoutBase = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.banda_bk);

            ImageView Img = new ImageView(this);

            if (random1 == 1) {
                Img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
                Img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                anim_translate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), translate);
                Img.startAnimation(anim_translate);
            }
            if (random1 == 2) {
                Img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView2);
                Img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                anim_translate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), translate);
                Img.startAnimation(anim_translate);
            }
            if (random1 == 3) {
                Img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView3);
                Img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                anim_translate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), translate);
                Img.startAnimation(anim_translate);
            }
            if (random1 == 4) {
                Img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView4);
                Img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                anim_translate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), translate);
                Img.startAnimation(anim_translate);
            }
            if (random1 == 5) {
                Img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView5);
                Img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                anim_translate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), translate);
                Img.startAnimation(anim_translate);
            }

            layoutBase.addView(Img);
        }
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to recreate layoutBase each time in loop

```
    int random1=random(5);
    int random2=random(9);
    RelativeLayout layoutBase = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.banda_bk);

    for(int i=1;i<=random2;i++) {
  ....
```

Get Relativelayout 1 time and add or remove children to it.

Comment: I've modified this, thanks. I still get  java.lang.NullPointerException here i think if (random1 == 1) {
                Img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
                Img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: check please that you have on appropriate layout all imageViews with id=ImageView1, id=ImageView2 and so on (you need to have all 5 ImageViews on layout).

Comment: Yes, they are on the layout, and they are hidden

Answer (score 0):

The error says is clear. Your ImageView is already placed in a container.
You need to call ViewGroup.RemoveChildAt (ie LinearLayout or what you use) on the container before adding it to layoutBase.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I added layoutBase.removeAllViews in my code, but now I get java.lang.NullPointerException.

I would like to keep in my layout random2 number of copies of the same image. And then I have to move all of them.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
    int random1=random(5);
    int random2=random(9);
    layoutBase.removeAllViews();

    for(int i=1;i<=random2;i++) {
```

Comment: You should provide some context for your answer and explain how it solves the OP's problem. Otherwise, there is a chance that it will be deleted, as it was automatically flagged as "low quality".

Comment: Okay.. From the next on wards i will do.